# A non-abelian and supersymmetric Stokes theorem for physics and mathematics?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Everyone in mathematics (differential geometry) and theoretical physics is aware of the generalized Stokes theorem for differential forms, namely
$$\int_\Sigma d\omega=\int_{\partial \Sigma}\omega$$
Question, is there any generalization of it for the following cases?

a) Superforms.

b) Non-abelian differential operators, $D_A=dA+A^2$.

Comment: Not an expert of supersymmetry but just googled [arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0002085](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0002085). Happy to see a more specific question.